# Why Do Game Center Group (grp) Names Work Inconsistently?

Tags: ios6, game-center

I had an existing & published game that used the GC leaderboard my.example.

I then created a new application that used the same leaderboards and thus put them in the same group.

I use my standard code for calling up leaderboards:

```
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardViewController 
     = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
leaderboardViewController.leaderboardDelegate = thisDelegate;
leaderboardViewController.category = thisBoard;
```

I've been testing this out and I get inconsistent results.

For the new (unpublished) game, I find that accessing the boards via grp.my.example works fine, as it should.

However, for my unpublished version of the old game I find that if I access the boards via grp.my.example this fails and I instead get the default board. However if I revert to my.example everything works fine.

To make things more complicated, I've added a new board, grp.my.newexample. For this board and this board only the old games requires grp.my.newexample.

Clearly I could code things to make the old game drop the grp prefix for the existing leaderboards. However, I worry that this is an Apple bug that only is set off until I rerelease my existing game.

Can any confirm if this problem will resolve itself (so that everything correctly uses grp) when I release?

Comment: Hi Shannon, did you solve your question? I'm in the same situation and I wonder if should update my exiting app to use the new names grp.myname or can I keem old names and only a new app should use new names?

Comment: I have also same issue. any update you get??

Comment: I just kludged things together as best I could by ignoring the "grp" prefix for existing boards on existing games. It'll probably break at some point when Apple fixes the original bug ...